# How to crop text in a QComboBox or how to get its actual width?

Tags: c++, qt, crop, qmessagebox

I want to crop a text in a `QComboBox`. But for this, I need to know the width of a QComboBox. And when I call something like this:

```
ui->qcombobox->width()
```

I get incorrect value (actual width is about 260 px but the resulting width is always 100 px).

**Questions:**

How can I get real width of a QComboBox ?

**OR**

How can I crop text depends on a QComboBox width?

Comment: what do you mean crop text if text is too long its just does "..." and you cant see what the rest of it says cus there isnt enough room in the combo box to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `ui->qcombobox->width()` in a constructor. Combobox's size is not calculated on this step yet. You need to wait until the first `showEvent` occures. Try something like this:

```
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::showEvent(e);
    qDebug() << ui->qcombobox->width();
}
```

In order to fill combobox on creating widget you need to do something like this:

```
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::showEvent(e);
    if (!mWasFilled) {
        mWasFilled = true;
        fillCombobox();
    }
}
```